# numpy array sort by Absolute value of line

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, sorting

i want to sort array by Absolute value of line
for example,

```
r = [[2, 3],
     [-3, 2],
     [-2, 1]]
```

to this

```
r = [[-2, 1],
     [2, 3],
     [-3, 2]]
```

and if Absolute value is same, I want it to sort by line value
i could do this for list like this

```
r.sort(key = lambda x:(abs(x[0]), x[0]))
```

Comment: By line value do you mean `x[1]` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to sort by sum of absolute values in each array, then by the first element:

```
sorted(r, key=lambda x: (np.abs(x).sum(), -x[0]))
```

Output:

```
[[-2, 1], [2, 3], [-3, 2]]
```

Comment: The question is poorly phrased, but I think that what is required is `np.array(sorted(r, key=lambda x:tuple(np.abs(x))))`. But I could be wrong - it's hard to understand the question.